# Spring Boot Metrics Error Affects Specific Functionalities and Web Services, Requires Pod Restart - How to Resolve?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, openshift

**Description:**
I'm currently facing an issue related to Spring Boot metrics in my application deployed on OpenShift 4. The error appears to impact specific functionalities such as Swagger and certain health web services. Notably, there is no discernible difference in behavior compared to other functionalities.

**Issue:**

The error manifests in functionalities like Swagger and some health web services. However, the error doesn't exhibit any unique characteristics compared to other parts of the application.

**Observations:**

The error persists even after a pod restart.
Restarting the pod temporarily resolves the issue, but it reoccurs consistently.

**Environment:**

Spring Boot application 2.1.3
Deployed on OpenShift 4

**Below is a snippet of the error:**

```
# HELP tomcat_sslhostconfig_opensslconfcontext Introspected attribute openSslConfContext (Tomcat<type=SSLHostConfig, ThreadPool="http-nio-8080", name="_default_"><>openSslConfContext)
# TYPE tomcat_sslhostconfig_opensslconfcontext untyped
tomcat_sslhostconfig_opensslconfcontext{threadpool="\"http-nio-8080\"",name="\"_default_\"",} 0.0
# HELP tomcat_protocolhandler_sslverifydepth Introspected attribute sSLVerifyDepth (Tomcat<type=ProtocolHandler, port=8080><>sSLVerifyDepth)
# TYPE tomcat_protocolhandler_sslverifydepth untyped
tomcat_protocolhandler_sslverifydepth{port="8080",} 10.0
# ... (and so on)
# HELP tomcat_servlet_loadtime Time taken to load and initialise the Servlet (Tomcat<j2eeType=Servlet, WebModule=//localhost/, name=dispatcherServlet, J2EEApplication=none, J2EEServer=none><>loadTime)
```

**What I've Tried:**
I've attempted to address the issue by restarting the pod, which provides a temporary resolution. However, the problem resurfaces upon subsequent usage.

**Additional Context:**

The error is specifically impacting Swagger and certain health web services.
There are no apparent distinctions in behavior between the affected functionalities and others.
The need for repeated pod restarts indicates a recurring issue.

**Request for Assistance:**
I'm seeking guidance on how to permanently resolve this issue without the need for frequent pod restarts.